# ID names of tags conflicting with JS function names

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that's submitted by JavaScript and something had broke it. The error given was

```
Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function
Source File: http://localhost/FormProcess.js
```

It turned out when the `id` attribute of an input field was assigned the value `submit` it screwed things up severely. Does this mean that id values can't be JavaScript reserved words? What I still don't get is `submit()` [isn't even  a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) so why would it cause a problem?

```
<input type="button" id="submit" onclick="check(document.getElementById('txt1'), document.getElementById('txt2'))" />
```

Conflicts with

```
document.getElementById("orderForm").submit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a form, the names and IDs of form controls are used to create named properties of the DOM form element, e.g.:

```
<form onsubmit="alert(this.foo.value);" ...>
  <input name="foo" value="bar">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So in the submit handler of the form, `this` references the form, and `this.foo` references the input with name *foo*. So if you have  form control with a name of "submit", then the submit property of the form will reference the control, not the submit method.

So never use form controls with names that are the same as standard form methods or properties, e.g. don't use form control names like "action", "name", "submit" or "reset".

BTW, "submit" is not a [reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1), it's just a standard method of a DOM form element.